# Displaying UITableViewCell's side by side, on the same row (As in Contacts -> Info)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

If one navigates to the iPhone's Phone app, then goes to Contacts -> Info (on any contact).. you will see at the bottom of the contact there are two adjacent UITableViewCells, on the same row. In this particular case, they are "Text Message" and "Add to Favorites"

How is this layout achieved? If there's any examples out there, that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would implement it is to create a UITableViewCell that is transparent, and add two UIButtons to the cell. That's what it looks like Contacts does to me.

Comment: That makes sense. Don't know why I didn't think of it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put the buttons in a `UIView` and use it as the table view's footer.  You can set up the footer view in IB and hook it up to an outlet and actions in your table view controller.  Then the code is a one-liner:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
}
```